# How use Case with than else when values is string or date in BigQuery?

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, case, aggregate

I have a BigQuery table like this:

```
+------+------------+------------------+
| Name |    date    | order_id | value |
+------+------------+----------+-------+
| JONES| 2019-01-03 | 11       |    10 |
| JONES| 2019-01-05 | 12       |    5  |
| JONES| 2019-06-03 | 13       |    15 |
| JONES| 2019-07-03 | 14       |    20 |
| John | 2019-07-23 | 15       |    10 |
+------+------------+----------+-------+
```

And needs add columns that have values from specific order_id (means order_id we don't know, can only count it), for example when order_count will be 3. For the first-order solution will be like this and found the last order_id is also not a huge problem:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT "JONES" name, DATE("2019-01-03") date, "11" order_id, 10 value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-01-05"), "12", 5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-06-03"), "13", 15
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-07-03"), "14", 20
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "John", DATE("2019-07-23"), "15", 10
)
SELECT name,
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(DATE as f_date) ORDER BY order_id LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*,
  max(order_id) AS l_id, 
  min(order_id) as f_id, 
  SUM(value) AS total
FROM DATA
GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------------+-----+------+
| name | f_id | f_date     |l_id | total|
+------+------+------------+-----+------+
| JONES| 11   | 2019-01-03 | 14  | 50   | 
| John | 15   | 2019-07-23 | 15  | 10   | 
+------+------+------------+-----+------+
```

Is there the same way to get values for the last order and values when the count order_id will be 3 by name?

Output:

```
+------+----------+----+----+-----+-----+----------+-----------+
| name |f_date    |f_id|l_id|total|3_id |  3_date  |  l_date   |
+------+----------+----+----+-----+-----+----------+-----------+
| JONES|2019-01-03| 11 | 14 |  50 |13   |2019-06-03| 2019-07-03|
| John |2019-07-23| 15 | 15 |  10 |NULL |NULL      | 2019-07-23|
+------+----------+----+----+-----+-----+----------+-----------+
```

I suppose there should be something with Case, but here is not works with aggregation for not numeric values :

```
(CASE WHEN order_id = l_id THEN date ELSE Null END) AS l_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT "JONES" name, DATE("2019-01-03") `date`, "11" order_id, 10 value UNION ALL
  SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-01-05"), "12", 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-06-03"), "13", 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-07-03"), "14", 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT "John", DATE("2019-07-23"), "15", 10
)
SELECT name,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(DATE AS f_date) ORDER BY order_id LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*,
  MAX(order_id) AS l_id, 
  MIN(order_id) AS f_id, 
  SUM(value) AS total,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(order_id AS `_3_order`, `date` AS `_3_date`) ORDER BY order_id LIMIT 3)[SAFE_OFFSET(2)].*,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(`date` AS l_date) ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM DATA t
GROUP BY name
```

with result

```
Row name    f_date      l_id    f_id    total   _3_order    _3_date     l_date   
1   JONES   2019-01-03  14      11      50      13          2019-06-03  2019-07-03   
2   John    2019-07-23  15      15      10      null        null        2019-07-23
```

Comment: @ Mikhail - one more question, if I need previous order_id that less than l_id can i do the same way with ARRAY_AGG?

Comment: @Anna - absolutely, please try by yourself first. if still challenge - let know so I will help with this too

Comment: Thank you, so for prev will be ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(`date` AS l_date) ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 2)[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].*, also Safe_OFFSET return NULL if out of range